# MySQL WHERE query problem (1241: Operand should contain 1 columns)

Tags: mysql, operands

I would like to retrieve some data from a large database. Essentially, values should be displayed (complete table) where the given players did not enter between the two dates.

The query would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM interiors 
WHERE OWNER = (SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE lastlogin BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2021-04-18');
```

I get the following error while running:

SQL error (1241): Operand should contain 1 column (s)

How would the query be correct and how could it work?

MySQL version= 5.7.32

Thank you very much for your help!

Richard

Comment: you must change **SELECT *** to **SELECT OWNER**

Comment: It didn’t get perfect that way either, but that’s how I was already able to work with it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you must post more infos about the tables and data if you want more help

Answer (score 0):

Correct query:

SELECT *
FROM interiors
WHERE owner IN (SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE lastlogin BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2021-04-18');

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **INNER JOIN**:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM interiors AS i
INNER JOIN accounts AS a 
ON  a.OWNER = i.OWNER
AND a.lastlogin BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2021-04-18';
```